# Replacing maximum value with minimum value in a array

Tags: java, arrays

First input is n numbers then the numbers itself, then find the maximum value and minimum value and last, replace the maximum value with the minimum one. But this code doesn't work first test case ( 5 1 3 3 3 4 ), it returns 3 3 3 3 3. But it works on second test case ( 8 5 4 2 2 4 2 2 5 ). What is wrong with this code ? I have checked the loop which check for maximum and minimum value, nothing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] marks = new int[sc.nextInt()];
     int max = 0;
     int min = 100;
     for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        marks[i] = sc.nextInt();
     }
     for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        if(min>marks[i]){
            min = marks[i];
        }
     }
     for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        if(max<marks[i]){
            max = marks[i];
        }
     }
     for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        if(marks[i]==max){
            marks[i]=min;
        }
    }
     for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        if(i!=marks.length-1){
            System.out.print(marks[i]+" ");
        }else{
            System.out.println(marks[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your first test case returns 1 3 3 3 1 when run on my machine.

Comment: Hey this works fine for me.

Comment: Code works fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/UiYlVh).

Comment: Ok so it's a problem from my machine. I'm using Sublime text by the way. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should work fine. I refactored it to make it more robust, readable and to make it easier to fire the test cases in a reproducable way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] first = new int[]{1, 3, 3, 3, 4};
    replaceMaxWithMin(first);
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    int[] second = new int[]{5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5};
    replaceMaxWithMin(second);
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    int[] fromScanner = readFromScanner();
    System.out.println("From scanner: " + Arrays.toString(fromScanner));
    replaceMaxWithMin(fromScanner);
}

private static void replaceMaxWithMin(int[] marks) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int mark : marks) {
        min = Math.min(min, mark);
        max = Math.max(max, mark);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
        if (marks[i] == max) {
            marks[i] = min;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
        if (i != marks.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(marks[i] + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(marks[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

private static int[] readFromScanner() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] marks = new int[sc.nextInt()];
    for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        marks[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    return marks;
}
```

The output for a run on my Java 8 JVM:

```
1 3 3 3 1

******************************************
2 4 2 2 4 2 2 2

******************************************
5 1 3 3 3 4   <--- what I typed into the console
From scanner: [1, 3, 3, 3, 4]
1 3 3 3 1
```

So the replacement code itelf works fine. Probably you have some weird problems with your entered data. You could also `println` the array before running your algorithm with `Arrays.toString(marks);`. At least for me, everything including reading from the scanner works fine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I just cross-checked your code and found that at
`int[] marks = new int[sc.nextInt()]` 
it will take only one integer and so the size of the array will be **the first integer entered**. So, to overcome through that you should predefine the size of the array **OR** you can take `ArrayList` for more convenience.

And, a little suggestion from my side is whenever you want to find the maximum or minimum from the elements of the array you can set the minimum and maximum variable as

```
min = arr[0];
max = arr[0];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
if(min>arr[i])
  min = arr[i];
if(max<arr[i])
  max = arr[i];
}
```

This will help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry, but your first sentence is just wrong. It reads the first entered input (the 5 or 8) and initializes the array with that size.

Comment: Better. But still no need for "you should predefine the size of the array OR" because that is exactly what the questioner does ;-)

And yes, I would also prefer an ArrayList for this so you don't need to enter the amount of numbers as first input :-)

Comment: ok, but I have mentioned that for more user convenience as the user will not have to change the array again and again in the code :)

Comment: There's no `n` defined in the OP's code and your code will fail, if the number of elements the user inputs is `0`. It would be preferable to use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as initial values for `min` and `max` respectively.